# How to read marks in text file to class variables?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file marks.txt which contains the marks of some students as:

```
23 32 45 
43 35 43 
34 42 45......
```

Each row represents the marks of one student in subjects like English, Maths, Science. What I want to do is to read these marks into an array of class objects so that I can work on them for comparing, marking etc. I could do it in C++ by creating an array of objects of class. But in Python how to do it and access them.

What I tried is--create a class with subjects as variables and a function to read the values from the file. But I am unable to get each record into a different class object. My code is given below:

```
        class Marks:
            Eng = Maths = Science = 0
            def getMarks():
                pass            #Not sure of the code
```

I used the following code to read the file.

```
    f = open("Marks.txt", 'r')
```

I created a list of objects to read the values.

```
    mark = [Marks() for i in range (x)] # x is the number of lines in file

    for m in mark:
        m.Eng, m.Maths, m.Science = f.read().split()
```

Here I am baffled as only the last record (line) is retained. But what I want to get is as many lists as there are records or students in the file as

```
mark(1) = [23, 32, 45]
mark(2) = [43, 35, 43]
mark (3) = [34, 42, 45]
```

What is the best possible way to do this with class or only list or dictionary? What I want is to be able to access each record, and the values of subjects separately.
Thank you

Comment: I worked out a solution for this. But any better solution is welcome. I created a list variable mylist to read data from the text file as mylist = list(map(int, f.read().split())). Now I have a list that included all the marks from the text file. Then I converted it into an array myArray by importing numpy as np and using the command myArray = np.array(mylsit). Then I used the reshape command (as I know the number of students and subjects) to reshape the array to get the desired output. I could access the marks by using the myArray[R][C} notation where R and C are row and column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
marks = []
for line in open("jpt1.csv"):
    marks.append(list(map(float,line.split())))

marks
```